# SwiftUI: "some View" in generic protocol

Tags: swiftui

How can I fix this code, so I have an easy way to render out all Animals.
Is it possible to make it work without using "AnyView" (Which works)

Thanks

// Error: No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'

```
protocol Animal {
    var name: String? { get }
    var age: Int { get } 

    associatedtype Body: View
    var view: Body { get }
}

struct Monkey: Animal {
    let name: String = "John"
    let age: Int = 3

    @ViewBuilder var view: some View {
        Text("I'm a monkey")
    }
}


struct AnimalsView: View {
    let animals: [any Animal] = [Monkey()]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<animals.count, id: \.self) { index in
                animals[index].view // ----> Error: No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**---- Update ----**

As @sweepers suggestions, I could add a global function (Global since it will be used in many different places and classes):

```
 struct AnimalsView: View {
    let animals: [any Animal] = [Monkey()]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<animals.count, id: \.self) { index in
                RenderAnimal(type: animals[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

// Outside class scope
    @ViewBuilder func RenderAnimal(type: any Animal) -> some View {
        if let monkey = type as? Monkey {
            monkey.view
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you find the need to put views in an array, it's probably time that you rethink your design. How about putting the *data* you have into an array, and create views from that data?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, the data is in the array!? And then the ForEach loop with iterate over the data and create the views.

Comment: As far as I can see, `Animal` does not represent *data*. Its requirements are almost the same as the SwiftUI `View` protocol. It's practically just a `View`. If you have other data that you store there, you should separate that out into a struct, and store an array of that struct instead.

Comment: Got it! I updated the protocol to make it more clear

Comment: Okay, so make a struct with `name`, `age`, and an enum (or something else) representing the type of the animal. Now, you can store an array of those. Write a single `@ViewBuilder` function that makes a `View` from those three things.

Comment: Thanks, that will work. I updated the question with the code. However, It doesn't feel very nice to have to do it like that. I then must remember to add all new animal classes to this function, instead of just having each class conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the *data* and the *view*, by making an `Animal` struct, and an `AnimalView` struct.

```
struct Animal: Identifiable {
    enum Kind {
        case monkey, dog
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String?
    let age: Int
    let type: Kind
    
    // add these to make the use-site more readable
    static func monkey(_ name: String? = nil, age: Int) -> Animal {
        .init(name: name, age: age, type: .monkey)
    }
    
    static func dog(_ name: String? = nil, age: Int) -> Animal {
        .init(name: name, age: age, type: .dog)
    }
}

struct AnimalView: View {
    let animal: Animal
    
    var body: some View {
        switch animal.type {
        case .monkey:
            // as an example
            VStack {
                Text("Monkey")
                Text("Name: \(animal.name ?? "Some Monkey")")
                Text("Age: \(animal.age)")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
        case.dog:
            // as an example
            HStack {
                Text("Dog")
                Text("Name: \(animal.name ?? "Some Dog")")
                Text("Age: \(animal.age)")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using protocols, consider using an `enum` to encode the types of animals. When you add a new animal type, the `switch` becomes non-exhaustive and produces an error, so you don't forget to also change the view's implementation.

I also made animals `Identifiable` (feel free to implement `id` a different way). Using the index as the id of a `ForEach` can break animations when the indices of the items change, like when you reorder the array, or insert something at the start.

Now you can do:

```
let animals: [Animal] = [.monkey("Foo", age: 3), .dog(age: 4)]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(animals) { animal in
            AnimalView(animal: animal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice touch with the enum also! :)